# Zip with Comprehension dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, zip, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
names = ["Person1", "Person2", "Person3"]

jobs = ["It", "Worker", "Kid"]
```

I want to make dictionary with zip function

```
mydict = {key if key == "Person2" else "Something": value for key, value in zip(names, jobs)}
print(mydict)
```

As the result it prints:

```
{'Something': 'Kid', 'Person2': 'Worker'}
```

I would expect this:

```
{'Something': 'It', 'Person2': 'Worker', 'Something':'Kid'}
```

Why do I get other result?
Please help me.

Comment: What would you expect `mydict['Something']` to yield?

Comment: would it help if you `reversed(zip(names, jobs))`?